# Cannot burn nft using metaplex burn instruction

Tags: metaplex, nft

0I want to burn an nft using metaplex sdk. I am using the following burn Instruction:

```
 const transaction = new Transaction().add(
    mpl.createBurnNftInstruction({
      metadata: metadataPDA,
      owner: wallet.publicKey,
      mint: mintId,
      tokenAccount: tokenAccount,
      masterEditionAccount: masterEditionPDA,
      splTokenProgram: splToken.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    })
  );
```

I have checked multiple times to make sure that the instructions are correct and that the seeds are working fine. I am still getting the following error:

```
failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation…cessing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x75
```

Can anyone guide me what the issue can be here

I am using metaplex/spltoken sdk, its on devnet and im trying to burn editions nft

Comment: Devnet or mainnet? Which NFT exactly? Be aware that there are differenct burn instructions for normal NFTs and editions. Which sdk version are you using?

Comment: this might help -> https://github.com/loopcreativeandy/video-tutorial-resources/blob/main/nftBurn/nftBurner.ts